# Ecto query for selecting model without associated record

Tags: ecto

I have a `User` model that has many `Membership`. `Membership` has a field called `group_id`.

I want to get a list of `Users` who have no memberships with the `group_id` field not equal to `1`.

I tried this

```
from u in User, join: m in assoc(u, :memberships), where: m.group_id != 1
```

I have 3 users in my db and one of them have a membership with group_id = 1. So I am expecting my query to return 2 users who don't have the membership. But it return empty array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly fetch the users without a membership, you need to use a left join and find where the group_id is nil:

```
from u in User,
left_join: m in assoc(u, :memberships),
where: is_nil(m.group_id))
```

[What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) explains the differences between joins (left vs inner in this case.)

Comment: `where: is_nil(m.group_id)` return 2 items, but `where: m.group_id != 1` return empty array. Maybe it's silly but I can't understand this behaviour.